# Force Maven to use internal and external dependency jars

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins

I have Jenkins integrated to my Maven Selenium Java project. I have a 'SeleniumUtils-0.0.2-14.0.0.0.jar' which is referred in POM.xml as:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.disney.gqe</groupId>
            <artifactId>SeleniumUtils</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.2-14.0.0.0</version> 
</dependency>
```

This Jar was handed over to me locally by the previous coder. Back then Jenkins build was not implemented. 
The project runs fine locally in Eclipse referencing jar from m2/repo folder. When I build using 'clean install' in Jenkins I get an error:
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/disney/gqe/SeleniumUtils/0.0.2-14.0.0.0/SeleniumUtils-0.0.2-14.0.0.0.jar

I don't want Maven to search this jar in central as I have it locally. How can I locally add the file in Jenkins repo folder and build the project?

Comment: It would be great if you paste the error log here. I am assuming that this issue happens due to the artifact is not available in maven central repo, also I believe, if you do purge your local repo, apparently the same maven will not work from your local.

Comment: Run mvn install task for that JAR on the command line.  That'll write it to your local .m2.  mvn deploy writes to the external repo - two tasks, two commands.

Comment: I did this : mvn install:install-file  -Dfile=/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository/com/disney/gqe/SeleniumUtils/0.0.2-14.0.0.0/SeleniumUtils-0.0.2-14.0.0.0.jar  -DgroupId=com.disney.gqe -DartifactId=SeleniumUtils -Dversion=0.0.2-14.0.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar. It sill searches in central repo

Comment: When you say "I have it locally", do you mean it is locally deployed in a Maven repository at your site or simply only available on disk?

Comment: It's available on disk. Not deployed at site.

Answer (score 1):

@JFMeier is absolutely right, you should put the dependencies in a hosted Maven repository.

However, if you do not have one you can do this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.disney.gqe</groupId>
  <artifactId>SeleniumUtils</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.2-14.0.0.0</version> 
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>path/to/the/jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Please note, I am *not* saying this a good idea but a dependency with `system`scope will prevent Maven from looking up the dependency externally.

The problem with system-scoped dependencies is that now every time someone (else) needs to do a build, they will have to put the jar in the same location as you. You can circumvent this by introducing a property parameter in each user's `settings.xml`, but now you have a maintenance problem you need to manage.

You have been warned.

Comment: Thanks, opting this method for now. I am learning how to use Nexus or Archiva for hosting the file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Jenkins, you probably have a Nexus or Artifactory (this is at least the recommended place to store your built artifacts). This Nexus or Artifactory is also the place to put libraries like the one you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you build the project with "clean install" then it will by default clean the local .m2 repository and try to download it from the available list off repositories from local pom.xml or Settings.xml file.

If you have copied the jar locally in the repo then try building the project with just "install", without "clean".

Comment: `maven clean install` will not remove anything from your local repository

Answer (score -1):

You can enforce `updatePolicy` per your need to achieve it under `$USER_HOME/.m2/settings.xml`

http://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Repositories

> updatePolicy: This element specifies how often updates should attempt
>   to occur. Maven will compare the local POM’s timestamp (stored in a
>   repository’s maven-metadata file) to the remote. The choices are:
>   always, daily (default), interval:X (where X is an integer in minutes)
>   or never.